# Converting vertical coordinate system of LAS dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, lidar, vertical-transformation, lasd

I want to overlap both LiDAR data and SRTM data but they use different vertical coordinate systems.

I am using ArcMap 10.2 and I firstly created a LAS dataset and original vertical coordinate system of LAS dataset was Unknown VCS from ArcInfo Workstation (I didn't choose any vertical coordinate system. And this one appeared). And then, I created a new LAS dataset and chose vertical coordinate system as EGM96 which SRTM data and Google Earth have. But elevation values of LiDAR points did not change. Still have different values from Google Earth and SRTM data. I need LiDAR to have same elevation values with SRTM for the same region.

Is there a way to make LiDAR and SRTM data the same vertical values for the same point on the map?

Comment: Hi Welcome to GIS SE! For new users, check out our [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to become familiar with our Q and A format. We need more information, such as the program and version you are using and what you have tried.

Comment: What was the original vertical datum from your LiDAR file, and how did you change it (method and software)? Can you provide a sample file? Respond to comments by editing the question. Tks.

Comment: One can't reproject LAS Datasets, that is why your z values did not change. Here is a duplicate question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72356/converting-a-lasd-lidar-coordinate-system.